# tail -f development.log for .net MVC? How can I monitor my db activity?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**In short: I just want to be able to see how frequently my MVC app is reading/writing to its DB, and don't know how.**. In long, see below:

---

I'm following a tutorial where an individual uses Ruby on Rails and .Net MVC 4 (code first, entity framework).

In RoR, he demonstrates that the way he wrote a controller action was sub optimal, as it would query the database ~400 times.  To prove this, he typed tail -f log/development.log into a CLI, and sure enough, when he refreshed the page, hundreds of lines of text showed up in his log.

Is there an equivalent to this for .Net MVC?  Is there a way for me to know whether I'm abusing the db from code?  I'm still very new to SQL, so sentences like "use SQL Profiler" won't help much, sorry.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use Entity Framework. I'm not keeping up with its recent musings, but afaik EF has no easy support for logging. There is a sample project, see [Tracing and Caching for Entity Framework available on MSDN Code Gallery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx) which adds support for tracing. Not exactly trivial.

IF you would use good ole' LinqToSQL, that *does* have logging support, see [Profiling LINQ to SQL using the DataContext.Log Property](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/profiling_linq_to_sql_using_th.html) for an example.

But still, a much better alternative comes if you are willing to "use SQL Profiler". Perhaps this short tutorial video can help: [SQL Server Profiler Tutorial Video](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Using_SQL_Server_Profiler)